# How do i add actionbar sherlock to my project on BitBucket?

Tags: android, version-control, actionbarsherlock, bitbucket

I have a project that is using ActionbarSherlock. Everything is set up properly and it works.

However i wanted to add the ActionbarSherlock project to the repository of the project that is on BitBucket. This is so no one else has to set up ActionbarSherlock with my application they can just fork it and have no problems.

I Added the ActionbarSherlock folder, that is used when importing a project and creating the initial ActionbarSherlock project, to my git folder. But it has so many classes and resources i figured there is a better way to add it to BitBucket instead of committing all of those things individually.

Comment: FYI: I would recommend ActionBarCompat for future maintainability... (and not ActionBarSherlock). Just a suggestion.

Comment: I'll look into that. I'm guessing ActionBarCompat is a different library. What makes it better?

Comment: It is the one that Google has released a few months ago, and is recommended as the new approach over ActionBarSherlock (arguably..)

Comment: Just a note: ABS has a lower minimun sdk version requirement than ABC, so check that if your project requires a low min sdk version.

Answer (score 1):

Actionbarsherlock is available on the central maven repository, so you just need to add a builder like Maven or Gradle to your project, and then add the correct dependency.

This is the best solution, what if later you add another libraries to your project, are you going to add them in your repository too ?